# IndexOutOfBound when grabbing filtered item from custom list view

Tags: android, arrays, listview, filter

I've created a custom listview which generates the correct data but when I try to search for a specific item by its name, it returns the correct item but then crashes 1 second later due to an IndexOutOfBoundException, not quite sure why considering I've initialized all arrays to the correct size.

[BossAdapter.java](http://paste.ofcode.org/JmasJEuGh2iBdppfqpjn8Y)  [Boss.java](http://paste.ofcode.org/pSGmkw7jPhKtwkYZjtq5P8)

```
ListView listView;
int[] boss_icon = {R.drawable.boss_1, R.drawable.boss_2, R.drawable.boss_3,
        R.drawable.boss_4, R.drawable.boss_5, R.drawable.boss_6, R.drawable.boss_7,
        R.drawable.boss_8, R.drawable.boss_9, R.drawable.boss_10, R.drawable.boss_11,
        R.drawable.boss_12, R.drawable.boss_13, R.drawable.boss_14, R.drawable.boss_15,
        R.drawable.boss_16, R.drawable.boss_17, R.drawable.boss_18};
String[] boss_title=  new String[18];
BossAdapter adapter;
String[] bossTime=  new String[18];
Handler handler;
String[] bossAppearance=  new String[18];
EditText search_view;
ArrayList<Boss> bossList;
int bossID;

private int getID(String name){
    int id = 0;

    switch(name){
        case "다크 지란트":
            id = 0;
            return id;
        case "머쉬맘":
            id = 1;
            return id;
        case "MARK52 ALPHA":
            id = 2;
            return id;
        case "깡패 바라하":
            id = 3;
            return id;
        case "데블린 워리어":
            id = 4;
            return id;
        case "닉시":
            id = 5;
            return id;
        case "에피":
            id = 6;
            return id;
        case "자이언트 라바아이":
            id = 7;
            return id;
        case "둔둔":
            id = 8;
            return id;
        case "레버넌트 좀비":
            id = 9;
            return id;
        case "우르자":
            id = 10;
            return id;
        case "부기콜리":
            id = 11;
            return id;
        case "그리폰":
            id = 12;
            return id;
        case "프랑케네뜨":
            id = 13;
            return id;
        case "경비대장 차우":
            id = 14;
            return id;
        case "그리피나":
            id = 15;
            return id;
        case "매드오네뜨":
            id = 16;
            return id;
        case "자이언트 터틀":
            id = 17;
            return id;
    }

    return id;
}
private void createListview(){
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    search_view = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_text);

    boss_title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.boss_array);

    bossList = new ArrayList<Boss>();


    adapter = new BossAdapter(getApplicationContext(), bossList);


    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    bossTime = getKoreanTime();


    // Moved our object creation here, so that it should only be done once.
    for (String boss : boss_title) {
        bossID = getID(boss);
        bossAppearance = bossAppearance(bossID);


        Boss bossObject = new Boss(boss_icon[bossID], boss, bossTime[bossID], bossAppearance[bossID]);
        bossList.add(bossObject);

    }



    handler = new Handler();
    Runnable update = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bossTime = getKoreanTime();
            int count = adapter.getCount();

            for(String boss: boss_title){
                bossID = getID(boss);
                bossAppearance = bossAppearance(bossID);
                ((Boss) adapter.getItem(bossID)).setBoss_time(bossTime[bossID]); // Re-set time
                ((Boss) adapter.getItem(bossID)).setBoss_appearance(bossAppearance[bossID]);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify our update
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(update, 10);

    EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_text);
    myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

Strings.xml

Boss Timer

```
<string-array name="boss_array">
    <item>다크 지란트</item>
    <item>머쉬맘</item>
    <item>MARK52 ALPHA</item>
    <item>깡패 바라하</item>
    <item>데블린 워리어</item>
    <item>닉시</item>
    <item>에피</item>
    <item>자이언트 라바아이</item>
    <item>둔둔</item>
    <item>레버넌트 좀비</item>
    <item>우르자</item>
    <item>부기콜리</item>
    <item>그리폰</item>
    <item>프랑케네뜨</item>
    <item>경비대장 차우</item>
    <item>그리피나</item>
    <item>매드오네뜨</item>
    <item>자이언트 터틀</item>

</string-array>
```

LOGCAT

```
07-24 17:11:18.628  11159-11159/baegmon.com.bosstimer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: baegmon.com.bosstimer, PID: 11159
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at baegmon.com.bosstimer.BossAdapter.getItem(BossAdapter.java:38)
        at baegmon.com.bosstimer.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:158)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Show us this: at baegmon.com.bosstimer.BossAdapter.getItem(BossAdapter.java:38)

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić sorry editted in the adapter file

Comment: Can we see R.array.boss_array please?

Comment: May i know why you are using handler to update the adapter data, you are trying to update the vales after 1000ms in the mean time adapter count may changes, so check it

Comment: @bGorie because I'm doing a countdown of time so it needs to keep being updated

Comment: which is the mainActivity Line 158, I think the problem is there with handler. Comment the handler code and try to search it, Let see what is going to happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>This is the problem!</strike>

```
bossList = new ArrayList<Boss>();
adapter = new BossAdapter(getApplicationContext(), bossList);
```

You populate the bossList after passing it to the adapter!

```
for (String boss : boss_title) {
    bossID = getID(boss);
    bossAppearance = bossAppearance(bossID);


    Boss bossObject = new Boss(boss_icon[bossID], boss, bossTime[bossID], bossAppearance[bossID]);
    bossList.add(bossObject);

}
```

Seems like I was wrong, the problem could be in the R.array.boss_array resource!

After seeing the resource could the encoding be the problem?
One entry is: `<item>MARK52 ALPHA</item>` and all the others are something in Korean. Could that possibly cause an issue?

Try changing one of the values to something like 'example' and run it again. If the error says that the array size is 2 than that is your problem.

You should also call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after adding or removing items from the list!

Comment: @Baegmon if this answer solved your problem please consider marking it as correct after the 15 minute period! Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: sorry I'm slightly confused, I add to the bossList in the forloop before

Comment: You actually populate it after, put it above the first snippet and it will work!

Comment: Populating list after passing it to adapter is **okay**. That is the natural pattern in Android. You update the list and call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

Comment: The R.array.boss_array is just a list of strings with a bunch of names

Comment: Also tried what you suggested, does not matter what language it is still gives me an error and also tried notifydataset changes everywhere else still results in errors :/

Comment: @Beagmon but does the error say now Invalid index 2, size is 2? And if you change one more does it say Invalid index 3, size is 3?

Comment: @Roberto woops it changes to how many results the search returns. if 1 result is returned invalid index 1, size is 1, if 2 results, invalid index 2 size is 2 etc

Comment: Then the problem is in the encoding, try changing it all to English 99% chance it will work @Baegmon

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić tried that but still the same errors unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to notify the adapter about the change in dataset.

```
// Moved our object creation here, so that it should only be done once.
for (String boss : boss_title) {
    ...
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // This is required
```

Just to avoid any confusion, the above for loop is the **first** one shown in code.

Comment: Is this after the first for-loop?

I already did this after the change in dataset

Comment: Edited my answer. Yes, it is the first for loop.

Comment: tried it, still returns java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2

Comment: Please show us what is line 158 of `MainActivity.java`.

Comment: it is ((Boss) adapter.getItem(bossID)).setBoss_appearance(bossAppearance[bossID]);
from the second forloop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem, boss_title having 18 items. You are trying to iterating the loop from 0 to 18 and after that you are getting the nth item which is not there in the list.

```
((Boss) adapter.getItem(bossID)).setBoss_time(bossTime[bossID]);
```

bossID may be something else which is greater than the size of the list

....

```
for(String boss: boss_title){
                bossID = getID(boss);
                bossAppearance = bossAppearance(bossID);
                ((Boss) adapter.getItem(bossID)).setBoss_time(bossTime[bossID]); // Re-set time
                ((Boss) adapter.getItem(bossID)).setBoss_appearance(bossAppearance[bossID]);
            }
```

Comment: @bGorie but in the getID methods I make it so that the returned ID is only the numbers that are assigned to each item so would that still be a problem?

Comment: yes bossId may be from 0 to 17, but bossList size may less than that because  you are filtering the data.